# How to manage two different applicationId in productFlavors?

Tags: android, android-productflavors, android-build-flavors

I need to manage two different client code in single project so i have used productFlavors and defined flavor for each client.

Now the question is source code base is same for both but need to define different `applicationId` like

1. com.abc
2. com.def.

How would I make flavor so that code remain same for both and `appId` different?

Comment: Which code are you talking about? How does your code depend on application id?

Comment: You can just add suffix to applicationId like this `applicationIdSuffix ".test"` .

Comment: You can as well do this manually by right clicking on app module and create new java folder, then, in the folder, create a new package

Comment: @Khemraj Simple question let say two customer.
1.Apple (com.au.apple)
2. Google (com.uk.google)

Project code will remain same just logo will change for both. In this case how would I define above applicationId so that both can use common code.

Answer (score 3):

Android will create `main/` source set and directories for everything you want to share between all your build variants, so no need for creating new source set in your case.

And you could use `applicationIdSuffix` for different build variants,which is appended to the "base" application id when calculating the final application id for a variant.

For example:-

```
flavorDimensions "appMode"

productFlavors {

    free {
        dimension "appMode"
        applicationIdSuffix ".free" //the application id of 'free' is com.example.com.free
    }
    paid {
        dimension "appMode"
        applicationIdSuffix ".paid"//the application id of 'free' is com.example.com.paid
    }
}
```

The applicationIdSuffix will be appended to the package name(base application id),
`com.example.com` is the package name in above example.

Answer (score 2):

add the code block set `applicationId` like below :

```
productFlavors {
        abc {
            resValue "string", "build_type", "Version " + defaultConfig.versionName
            applicationId "com.abc"
        }
        def {
            resValue "string", "build_type", "Version " + defaultConfig.versionName
            applicationId "com.def"
        }
```

Comment: What will be the package name? I want both flavor use common code. I dont want to make separate packages for both.

Comment: just define `applicationId "packageName"` it will remains your code same for both flavour just select flavour while making APK to set package name